# How to say 'Is climate change making them worse?', with 'them' referring to floods

Tags: preguntas

I am trying to say 'is climate change making them worse?' as a question, with 'them' referring to 'floods'. The full sentence is meant to be a title or slogan for something, like 'Floods in Ecuador; is climate change making them worse?'

I thought it might be something like:
¿El cambio climático les hace peor(es)? or 
¿El cambio climático les empeora?

I am probably wrong but I thought I'd have a go myself before asking the question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should go with "las", not "les". I'm not much of a grammar guy, but here "les" means "to them", not "them", so it sounds like the floods themselves are suffering or being affected (in a kind of personal way, if that makes sense).

"El cambio climático las empeora" or "El cambio climático las está empeorando" look fine to me.

Comment: Correct. The reason is that "las" is a direct object whereas "les" is an indirect object. You need a direct object here.